# Distribution for population growth

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

For the exponential population growth with a constant growth rate of $R$,
$$
n(t+1) = R*n(t)
$$
where $n$ is the number of individuals in the population. Therefore, we can sample from a Poisson distribution since the sum of $n$ numbers drawn from a Poisson distribution with mean $R$ is known to follow a Poisson distribution with mean $Rn$.

If $n=K$ remains constant and $R$ is a function of $t$, what distribution would,
$$
R(t+1) = R(t)*K
$$
would follow? Note that $R$ need not be an integer and so Poisson may not apply.

Comment: Please clarify!  Do you mean $R(t)=R(0)K^t$?  (Assuming $t$ an integer).

Comment: In fact, $R(t)= \alpha \log \frac{M}{G(t)}$ for some function $G(t)$. $\alpha$ and $M$ are constants.

Comment: You have $\frac{R(t+1)}{R(t)}=K$, a constant.  How do you get anything other than what I had ($R(t)=R(0)K^t$) in my previous comment?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made some calculations and the function $G$ is such that $R(t)=R(0)K^t$.